# Why Tomcat SSL does not work on port 443 on Ubuntu EC2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have installed openjdk+tomcat7 on ubuntu EC2 instance.
After do some test http and https on 8443 does work.
I have already configured security group to allow 8080/443/8443.
When i try to configure SSL on port 443, it will prompt "permission denied" when start Tomcat.
But i already start tomcat with root prev:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start
```

Do you have some idea about this?

Comment: I have do some search by Google, i know the TCP port below 1024 must need root privileged. But i start tomcat via "sudo", doesn't it mean to use root? I'm a newbie to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in /etc/default for a file called "tomcat7". Change the username and password in there.

```
# Run Tomcat as this user ID. Not setting this or leaving it blank will use the
# default of tomcat6.
TOMCAT7_USER=root

# Run Tomcat as this group ID. Not setting this or leaving it blank will use
# the default of tomcat6.
TOMCAT7_GROUP=root
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is addressed [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464926/linux-in-ec2amazon-cannot-use-port-80-for-tomcat). Changing the user tomcat runs under to root is not a good idea for security reasons.