# Cannot access Tomcat via web after EC2 reboot

Tags: linux, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, portforwarding

I rebooted my Amazon EC2 instance, and now I can't connect to my Tomcat7 web server via the web.

Here's what I've tried, to no avail:
1) Confirmed that my settings are correct in Tomcat's server.xml file:

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000" />
               redirectPort="8443" />

    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
... />
```

2) updated my iptables via [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464926/linux-in-ec2amazon-cannot-use-port-80-for-tomcat):

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

3) Reviewed my tomcat catalina.out log (success, no errors)

4) Tried connecting to my domain via ip. It redirects to https, but doesn't show anything.  I cannot get either of my webapps up, nor the Tomcat7 homepage.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I can SSH and SCP into the system, so I think the issue is either with Tomcat or some sort of DNS resolution.  My domain is registered with namecheap and hosted on AWS.  On namecheap, I have forwarding set up using the 'A Address'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like my iptables commands may have been off a bit.  Here's what I ran to get it to work:

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <my_ip_address,my_ip_address> --dport 80 -j  REDIRECT --to-port 8080
/sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <my_ip_address,my_ip_address> --dport 443 -j  REDIRECT --to-port 8443
```

It looks like I need to open up ports 443 and 8443 as well.  I'll leave this post up so others can refer to it if they come across the same issue.

**UPDATE:**
I also needed to update my server.xml, changing

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"  
 connectionTimeout="20000" />  
 redirectPort="8443" />
```

to:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"  
 connectionTimeout="20000" />  
 redirectPort="443" />
```